# Can I transitionTo a route in Ember.js application without models available?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, routes

I am implementing a calendar application in Ember. I have my router set up this way:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('month', { path: '/month/:year/:month' });
});
```

Now I would like to have buttons to navigate to the next or previous month. At that point I don't have the model for the next/previous month loaded, I only know what month and year I want to go to, so I'd expect being able to transition like this:

```
this.transitionTo('month', { year: 2014, month: 1 });
```

However, Ember will expect my parameter to be a model, will skip the Route#model hook on month route and directly set the provided object to the controller in Route#setupController.

I think my scenario is rather common and from my Googling it seems like it used to be supported, but it just does not work for me. Please, advice how I can transition to a route when all I know are the ids of the models involved and don't have access to the actual model instances.

Answer (score 2):

Since your route is a composite key, you're having to send in an object.  Ember considers an object to be the model for the route.  If you were to just send in a non object, or an `id` Ember would then hit the model hook and do what you are expecting.

So you're going to have to handle it in the setupController, here's the general idea

```
this.transitionTo('month', { year: 2014, month: 1, needsGetting: true });

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return ['red', 'yellow', 'blue'];
  },
  setupControler: function(controller, model){
    if(Em.get(model, needsGetting)){
       // model = get the model
    }
    this._super(controller, model);
  }
});
```

As mentioned in my comment you could also use the model hook

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return ['red', 'yellow', 'blue'];
  },
  setupControler: function(controller, model){
    if(Em.get(model, needsGetting)){
       //model = this.model(model);
       // model = get the model
    }
    this._super(controller, model);
  }
});
```

Or you can fetch the next model

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return ['red', 'yellow', 'blue'];
  },
  actions : {
    previous: function(){

    },
    next: function(){
      var model = this.get('currentModel');
      //figure out next hash
      var nextModel = this.model(nextModelParams);
      this.transitionTo('month', nextModel);
    }     
  }
});
```

Comment: It seems you are right. However I would argue that this should be a bug/feature request, as loading the model via model hook in my scenario is a legimate use-case. I definitely should not need to repeat my model loading logic anywhere. Thanks!

Comment: It's definitely not a bug, maybe a low priority feature.  Your situation creates a scenario where Ember itself couldn't know the difference between a model and a stubbed model.  Additionally you don't need to repeat your model fetching logic, you can call it from the `setupController` using `this.model(params)`.  Also since your transition happens in code, you could fetch the model in code and use `transitionTo` with the actual model (or even the promise to the model).